# Что это за операция над вектором?

Tags: математика, матрицы

Пытаюсь выяснить параметры камер и наткнулся на следующее
P=K∗[R∣t]
так же кое где мелькала формулировка
P=K∗[R t]

R - матрица 3х3 , t - вектор 3х1
что за операция | между данными величинами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По логике - это *комбинация* двух матриц. Т.е. матрица, в которой слева стоит матрица **R**, а справа  - **t**. Что-то типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]